# Relative module paths unresolved when loading ES Module from Blob

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, dynamic-import

To my knowledge, Data URIs created from a Blob have the same origin as the viewed page. I am using dynamic imports to conditionally load modules from a Blob source - as these modules may be stored locally, or from an otherwise non-server origin and loaded at runtime.

The problem comes with `import` statements inside these modules, of which import paths beginning in `/` or `./`, unlike a module loaded from a regular URL, throws `Error resolving module specifier "/(...).js"`

To illustrate, I have a minimal set of scripts here:

**main.js** (Webpage entry point)

```js
async function blob_from_url( url ) {
    const res = await fetch( url );
    return await res.blob();
}

function load_module_from_blob( blob ) {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );

    const module = import( url );

    URL.revokeObjectURL( url );
}

await load_module_from_blob( await blob_from_url( '/module.js' ) );
```

**lib.js** (Example lib the module imports)

```js
export const something = 2;
```

**module.js** (Module being dynamically imported)

```js
import { something } from '/lib.js';
```

Assuming that the origin is the same, the path `/lib.js` as an import should resolve to the server host, right?

Instead: `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “/lib.js”.`

Is this expected behaviour?

I was able to find a workaround for this, by prepending `window.location.origin`, and using a dynamic import:

**module.js**

```js
const { something } = await import( window.location.origin + '/lib.js' );
```

But this is extra boilerplate, and loses intellisense which I'd like to avoid both.

Comment: This is definitely expected behaviour. Things instantiated from blob and files don't have a filesystem. Internally, the document and sheet does not know or have a 'path' other thant the blob URL it was created from. This can work, if you make minified module files of it that collate all the imports. It's all or nothing here. Why do you want to do this? You are loading the file here anyway, why not directly import the `module`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. As stated in the original question I *need* to be able to load modules dynamically, not just from the webserver itself, but also from other string sources, including from file blobs stored in the browser's `indexedDB` - the usecase here is absolutely not a regular site, I can elaborate further if needed. Currently the workaround I'm thinking is to inject the expected imports directly by prepending them to the module string. In quick summary, the project this is for is a pseudo-OS, and these are Kernel modules.

Comment: This seems a bit too custom. Unless you can set the path somehow, your modules will _at most_ exist in some temporary directory somewhere, and not at the expected path. But if you got his deep in the woods, not sure I can help you there.

Comment: Thanks again for replying! This project goes *very* far off what JS is both intended for and what its tools generally can do. I've come up with a *terrible* solution to the problem which should be able to give me what I need - basically adding a packing step where libraries can be included statically, and the modules of a project are packed into a final singular file. There's a lot of restrictions in my solution but the intent is to preserve intellisense at all costs and the final experience to be similar enough to the "normal" way of using ES modules. Time for terrible preprocessing! :)

Comment: Pretty much just making an *awful* subset of what something like webpack can do, but running in the browser itself at runtime.

Comment: Why does the title say relative paths but none of your examples have a path starting with a `.`? I guess you mean relative to the document base. Have you tried `import.meta.url`? Sounds interesting what you’re doing though.